# How to load MSMQ cmdlets in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, msmq

Technet has a nice article ([Windows PowerShell for Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn264983.aspx)) listing a myriad of PowerShell cmdlets available on the latest OSes. Often there are easy (or not so easy:-) ways to backport some of those to earlier OSes. In particular I am interested in installing the MSMQ cmdlets in Windows 7. Can this be done and if so how? My searches thusfar have drawn a blank.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589843/accessing-msmq-via-powershell

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is an option. I believe it's specific to PowerShell 4 on Server 2012 / Windows 8. I couldn't find a separate installation for the MSMQ PowerShell module, but when I selected the MSMQ Server feature on my Server 2012 box and installed it, the MSMQ module became available.

-Joel

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is years old but I always get it when i was searching for information on getting the msmq cmdlets onto windows 7.

The only option that i have found is to install the [Pscx package](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Pscx/3.2.2) for powershell which gives you some if not all of the cmdlets that you need for MSMQ